# How to pass variables to IIFE function as global arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, arguments, iife

I'm seeking to pass `local variables` to IIFE (Module Pattern) as a `global arguments`, but I have no idea how do I do this.

Here I have one of my modules that needs to receive some `variables` as the `arguments` outside of module scope:

```
const Event = (function(flag, length) {
    console.log(flag, length);

    function drive(target, event, callback) {
        let isStringArray = Array.isArray(event);
        if (isStringArray) {
            event.forEach(string => register(target, string, callback))
        }
    }
    function register(target, event, callback) {
        target.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.addEventListener(event, callback)
        })
    }
    return {
        drive: drive
    }
})();

export default Event;
```

And this is my main code:

```
import Event from './event.js';
import Process from './process.js';

class Slider {
    constructor(root, elem, event, process) {
        /* Instance Arguments */
        this.root = document.getElementById(root);
        this.elem = this.root.querySelectorAll(elem);

        /* Local Variables that need to pass to Module Pattern. */
        this.flag = true;
        this.length = this.elem.length;

        /* Global Modules */
        this.Event = event(this.flag, this.length); // doesn't work. 
        this.Process = process;
        this.Setup;
    }
    get Setup() {
        this.Event.drive(this.elem, ['mouseenter', 'click'], (e) => this.Process.finish(e));
    }
}

let slider = new Slider('slider', '.image', Event, Process);
```

[Full Code](https://repl.it/@sniffingdoggo/Change-Class-Syntax-to-Module-Pattern)

Like I said, I want to pass the local variables to my module for being able to inspect the arguments globally inside of the scope.

I could just pass the variables to `this.Event.drive(this.flag, this.length)` directly like we normally do, but it would looks a bit dirty and ugly so I'm not going to use this way unless there are 0 ways.

Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Thanks to listen.

Answer (score 1):

### IIFE

as name says it immediate invoking function so you can pass variable as an argument because it already executed till then.

you can pass value in as below

```
var event = (function(name){return name})('value');
```

Comment: Well, this allows only to pass the variables that in the same javascript file. I can't still pass the local variable `this.flag` and `this.length` to `Event` module.